# For Loop Changes randomnumber

Tags: java

My RandomNumber value changes in my for loop statement.  This prevents the program from actually matching the RandomNumber generated with the number entered by the user. How can I modify my for loop so that it does not affect the RandomNumber?

This is the java code I did in NetBeans;

```
package numberguess;

/**
 * 
 * @author Marion
 */
public class NumberGuess {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randNum = 0, guessNum = 0;
        // Generates a random number from 1 to 10
        randNum = new java.util.Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.println("I am thinking of a random number from 1 to 10");
        for (randNum = 0; randNum < 3; randNum = randNum + 1) {
            System.out.print("Guess?");
            java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
            guessNum = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You guessed " + guessNum);
            if (randNum == guessNum) {
                System.out.println("You Guessed it!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put randNum in the loop.  Use something else, like numGuesses.

Comment: at this line 
     for (randNum = 0; randNum <3; randNum = randNum + 1)

you are over writing your randNum variable

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a different variable for counting in the loop. You're assigning to randNum in

```
for (randNum = 0; randNum <3; randNum = randNum + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (randNum = 0; randNum <3; randNum = randNum + 1)
```

change to

```
for (int i= 0; i<3; i = i+ 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here: Please note that I moved the Scanner outside the loop since you do not need to have it created multiple times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int randNum = randNum = new java.util.Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
    int guessNum = 0;
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("I am thinking of a random number from 1 to 10");
    for(int i =0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Guess?");
        guessNum = scanner.nextInt();
        if(randNum == guessNum) {
            System.out.println("You Guessed it!");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("You guessed " + guessNum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this change the code logic.. I guess he wanted to have 3 attempts to guess the number.

Comment: oh I see, modified the code to reflect the original logic. Thank you Maarty

Answer (score 1):

I have just assign another variable for for loop.

```
for (int rand1 = 0; rand1 <3; rand1 = rand1 + 1)
{

      if (rand1 == guessNum)
      { 
                System.out.println("You Guessed it!");
                        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Using a for loop, ask for three guesses. You can use the following
code to ask for a guess and Using an if statement in the for block, determine whether randNum and guessNum are equal. these are the conditions the for loop and if statement should meet